# Error in loading JSON data - can't find the file

Tags: python, json, file, directory, filenotfounderror

I've been trying to solve this issue, but right now I need some help. I'm trying to upload this JSON file (DBL) in Spyder IDE. I have stored the JSON-data file and the Spyder file, in the same map in order to read the JSON file, but it's not working.

My Python code:

```
import json 

file = open("dbl")

dbl = json.load(file)

print(dbl)
```

Every time I upload the json file, in the same map as the spyder.py file, it can't recognize the file directory.

I have stored the my .py file in [the same folder as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4I93.png) the JSON file.

This is the error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dbl.json'
```

Comment: Is the file called `'dbl'`? There is no file extension?

Comment: Please add `import os; print(os.listdir())` to your code and post the output. Note that newlines don't render in inline code blocks, please replace the `;` with a newline appropriate for your platform.

Comment: You must include the `.json` file name extension when opening the file. If that doesn't work, it's probably because the current working directory is not the one the script and the data file are in when the script is run (a common problem when using IDEs like spyder). You can workaround that by using `open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "dbl.json"))`.

Comment: @MichaelRuth: This is the output: runfile('C:/Users/balas/OneDrive/Skrivebord/DataScienceOpg/import_data.py', wdir='C:/Users/balas/OneDrive/Skrivebord/DataScienceOpg')
['dbl.json.json', 'import_data.py']
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: It looks like somehow the JSON file has *two* `.json` file extensions. If that is true you will need to use the name `"dbl.json.json"` to open it. Note that by default, Windows hides file name extensions, so you should turn that off to avoid confusion like this.

Comment: @martineau I will try figure this out. But I really appreaciate your help!

Comment: See [How to show or hide file extensions in Windows 10](https://www.techadvisor.com/how-to/windows/windows-10-file-extensions-3697651/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file, in fact, does not exist. The actual filename is dbl.json.json.

```py
import json 
file = open("dbl.json.json")
dbl = json.load(file)
print(dbl)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is fine, however, it's good practice to add a file extension. Looks like you forgot to add the extension.
You are using relative paths. It is advised to use absolute paths. In this case, put the python script and db1 file in the same directory and try again.

In case, you want to debug just add the below code on top of your script to see if the file is present or not and modify the script accordingly.

```
import os; 
print(os.listdir())
```

Comment: The code isn't fine if it doesn't work. It's not simply a "good practice" to include the file's extension when opening the file, it's a requirement.

Comment: Thx. But I get this error message: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 363099: character maps to <undefined>

Answer (score 0):

if dbl is name of json file then you should add ".json" extension too. you might do this:

````
   
# Opening JSON file
f = open('dbl.json',)
   
# returns JSON object as 
# a dictionary
data = json.load(f)
   
# Iterating through the json
# list
for i in data:
    print(i)
   
# Closing file
f.close()```
````

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've previously tried that approach, but it keep says: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dbl.json'

Comment: Enter this code and see if the current directory is the same as directory of the .json file or not... they might be in different directory I believe```import os 
print(os.getcwd())
```

Comment: Yes, its in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

You'll use ".json" in the file path.
For example:

```
file = open("dbl.json")
```

Comment: It keeps telling me this: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dbl.json'

Comment: @Yousef, this is because dbl.json does not exist in the current working directory

Comment: Please check attached (latest)

Comment: Probably, your path is wrong. You can control the file path. The file should be in the project file.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this issue too. My guess is that If you use a non-default serialization method to serialize the data and save it in a Json file, then apparently Json has trouble in recognizing this file when you try to open it. It has nothing to do with the suffix. A Json file does not need to be named with 'json' as the suffix. This has everything to do with the fact that sometimes people will take a customized approach and overwrite the default method of serialization of Json. This is fine when you don't try to save the serialized data in a file. The file you are reading or opening is probably not serialized in a 'classical' way and Json has issuer in recognizing it as a legitimate Json file.

I am having this issue right now. It probably has nothing to do with the file name or the path in which the file is saved or stored.